# Confusion regarding finding the number of extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, group-cohomology

Where extension is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension.

We have that, $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{4}) = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. We have that, $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4)  = \{f,g\}$, where: $f(1) = 1$ and $g(1) = 3$.

We must now find all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ to $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{4})$. The number of such homomorphisms would be the number of Homs from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is equal to $\gcd(3,2) = 1$. So we only have the trivial hom which is $\alpha(x) = f$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. We now reference this part of  Dummit and Foote:
[image]

We have that, $A^{G} = \mathbb{Z}_4$, because every point is a fixed point with regards to the only hom $\alpha$ (the action induced by it). Now here is my confusion, what do they mean by $NA$ in this text since I'm trying to compute,
$$H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_4)?$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The $N$ stands for Norm. If $G$ is finite. We define for a $G$-Module $A$ the norm
$$N: A \to A, x \mapsto \sum_g gx.$$
Here we resolve $A=\mathbb{Z}$ with the above complex. Since (by convention) every group acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $A^G=A$. And the norm is just multiplication by the cardinality of $G$. So $$H^2(G,A)=A^G/NA=\mathbb{Z}/\# G \mathbb{Z}. $$

Remark: it is not a coincidence that the cohomology groups are cyclic. All these formulae follow from the machinery of Tate-Cohomology (see e.g. Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg, Cohomology of Number Fields).